# how to get sum() from alise column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sum

I'd like the sum of TotalVisitedTime time but it is alias column so how can I gtt it?

```
Select CONVERT(varchar(6), DATEDIFF(second, [Start], [End])/3600)
   + ':'
   + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (DATEDIFF(second, [Start], [End]) % 3600) / 60), 2)
   + ':'
   + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEDIFF(second, [Start], [End]) % 60), 2) AS TotalVisitedTime
FROM [Table Name]
```

Note: [Start] and [End] are columns name.

Comment: i want to sum of TotalVisitedTime time but it is alise column so how can i got it????? Plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(TotalVisitedTime)
FROM (    
    -- AS PER @Alex Aza,  @Andriy M     
        SELECT 1234 AS TotalVisitedTime
     ) AS OuterTable
```

Comment: I was wondering what would be the result of summing up of two varchar values like '01:00:00' and '02:00:00' :).

Comment: lolz, i was expecting the person asking the question would fill in his code to do the donkey work of doing the Math :D. Jokes apart, i wanted to guide the poster to know the concept of wrapping Query into a Set and using computed columns!

Comment: @Akhil: There's nothing wrong with the approach itself. But you should agree that it cannot be applied here the way you are offering it to be applied, because the column is non-numeric. I mean, your solution would be valid if it was applicable, which it is not.

Comment: @Andriy: ok. how about this? SELECT 'ABC', (SELECT 'CDE') AS tt

Comment: It has nothing to do with your solution. You were probably addressing @Alex Aza in the other comment thread?

Comment: @Alex Aza: as i said "syntax wise" as u just seem to care about syntax, rather than what the posters intent was?!

Comment: @Andriy: In my view answering the posters question is important, than being the devils advocate!!

Comment: Also, i did not offer anything. I just modified posters query, just to illustrate using SUM on alias column!

Comment: @Akhil - Query like this `SELECT ColumnName, (SELECT ColumnName FROM TABLE) tt` is not valid `syntax-wise`, as `ColumnName` is not referred to any table anymore.

Comment: im enlightened, lolz. 'ABC' in my example was not a column, rather a string. SQL allows SELECT '1' do you think '1' is a column?

Comment: @Akhil - I'm sorry, you completely lost me. I thought we were talking about how you proposed to add `,` to my query and I said that it would not be the fix, neither from functional nor syntax point of view.

Comment: You are mistaken there, I'm not advocating anyone. If no one had commented on or downvoted your answer, I would still left my comment to the point expressed there, i.e. that *your solution* is basically fine, but it's not applicable here the way you have described it. This is not about syntax, this is about the validity of the approach as applied to a not so specific problem. (I mean, you solution would still be inapplicable to *any* non-numeric column/expression, not just to the one in the OP's query.)

Comment: Ah. sry, i lost u ovr thr :) anyways, im of the belief that posters bigger issue whould be addressed, and u are that it should be syntactically correct. i concede if we could stop the Thread here :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes sense to sum up seconds and then do the conversion you are trying to do.

```
SELECT  CONVERT(varchar(6), diff/3600)
    + ':'
    + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (diff % 3600) / 60), 2)
    + ':'
    + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), diff % 60), 2) AS TotalVisitedTime
FROM 
(
    select sum(DATEDIFF(second, [Start], [End]) diff
    from [Table Name]
) tt
```

Comment: How is it answering the posters question of "computing the SUM of alias column"? i do agree its an alternative way for the posters end result though!

Comment: Also, you need a "," after TotalVisitedTime And Query following it. it throws an ERROR when u run your query!!

Comment: @Akhil - fixed. `FROM` was missing, not the comma.

Comment: @Akhil - it definitely would not fix the syntax.

Comment: why wouldnt it fix it? to simplify, its like SELECT 1 AS totalVisitedTime, (SELECT 1) tt.

Comment: @Akhil - first of all this query would not make any sense. Secondly, the top query is using data from the subquery.

Comment: Thanks D :) I got a solution.